# On the definition of the volume form in general vector spaces as given in Spivak, Calculus on Manifolds

Tags: linear-algebra, differential-geometry, determinant, differential-forms

For a vector space $V$ denote by $\Lambda^k(V)$ the space of alternating $k$-tensors, or alternating $k$-fold multilinear maps on $V$. I have some difficulty following the intention of the author in the part where he introduced the volume form of a finite-dimensional vector space $V$ (page 83):

> The fact that $\dim \Lambda^n(\mathbb R^n) = 1$ is probably not new to you, since $\det$ is often defined as the unique element $\omega \in \Lambda^n(\mathbb R^n)$ such that $\omega(e_1, \ldots, e_n) = 1$. For a general vector space $V$ there is no extra criterion of this sort to distinguish a particular $\omega \in \Lambda^n(V)$. Suppose, however, that an inner product $T$ for $V$ is given. If $v_1, \ldots, v_n$ and $w_1, \ldots, w_n$ are two bases which are orthonormal with respect to $T$, and the matrix $A = (a_{ij})$ is defined by $w_i = \sum_{j=1}^n a_{ij} v_j$, then
>   $$
>  \delta_{ij} = T(w_i, w_j) = \sum_{k,l = 1}^n a_{ik}a_{jl} T(v_k, v_j) = \sum_{k=1}^n a_{ik}a_{jk}.
> $$
>   In other words, if $A^T$ denotes the transpose of the matrix $A$, then we have $A \cdot A^T = I$, so $\det A = \pm 1$. It folows as $\omega(w_1,\ldots, w_n) = \det(A)\cdot \omega(v_1, \ldots, v_n)$ that if $\omega \in \Lambda^n(V)$ satisfies $\omega(v_1, \ldots, v_n) \in \{-1,1\}$, then $\omega(w_1, \ldots, w_n) \in \{-1,1\}$. If an orientation $\mu$ for $V$ has also been given, it follows that there is a unique $\omega \in \Lambda^n(V)$ such that $\omega(v_1, \ldots, v_n) = 1$ whenever $v_1, \ldots, v_n$ is an orthonormal basis such that $[v_1,\ldots, v_n] = \mu$. This unique $\omega$ is called the *volume element* of $V$.

First why he claims that for a general (finite-dimensional) $V$ there is no extra criterion as for $\mathbb R^n$; if we choose some basis $v_1, \ldots, v_n$ of $V$ then the requirement $\omega(v_1, \ldots, v_n) = 1$ gives me a unique $n$-form (as the value on every permutation of the basis vectors is then also prescribed). Of course, this choice is relative to a basis, but that was the choice in $\mathbb R^n$ also. And the orientation is coded in the basis. So why all these complicated derivations using the given orientation and an inner product, when simply a basis is enough?

Also if we have a basis of a finite-dimensional vector space, we also get an inner product by multiplying the coefficient w.r.t. this basis and summing. Of course the geometric meaning of such an inner product is questionable, as it no longer corresponds to angles, length and projections as in the $\mathbb R^n$ setting with the standard inner product if the $v_i$ are not orthonormal. But for mere existence of an inner product such that the basis is orthonormal w.r.t. it, it is enough.

I can image that such definitions are not very meaningful from a geometrical point of view, if we take an arbitrary basis then built our volume form by the mere requirement that it takes the value one on this basis, we have no ready-to-use interpretation of it as an actual volume, as for it we need orthonormality and a notion of length, angle and so on already given by a prescribed inner product. (of course by the above construction of inner product an angle of two vectors w.r.t. to this constructed inner product corresponds to the "real" geometric angle if we view the coordinates as coordinates of the standard basis in $\mathbb R^n$). So I guess that what he might want to say is "there is no sort to distinguish any particular form that has also any meaningful geometrical interpretation, as for example given by some inner product and orientation, after which we can talk about (oriented) length, areas, volumes". But this is just a guess of mine; as how we are interested in "real world interpretations" in formal mathematics and its definition is here not clear to me.

Maybe what he want to say is that the essential ingredients for a volume form (as derived from $\mathbb R^3$ and its interpretation of volume) is that we need an orthonormal basis (hence an inner product), which also fixes an orientation, such that a meaningful volume form could be introduced.

Comment: As for your first question: the choice in case of a Euclidean space does _not_ depend on the choice of a basis, but (only) on the choice of a scalar product (which implies a definition of lengths and angles). This is quite a difference.

Comment: @Thomas Why that? The requirment $\omega(e_1, \ldots, e_n) = 1$ depends on the basis, if I choose a different basis $v_1, \ldots, v_n$ and require $\omega(v_1, \ldots, v_n) = 1$ I get a different volume form, or not? Could you please elaborate...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, it's true that a choice of basis determines an element of $\Lambda^n(V)$. But that's not very useful for manifolds, because there's rarely a natural way to single out a particular basis of each tangent space on a smooth manifold.

The point is that you don't need anything as specific as a choice of basis to determine a unique $n$-form. For example, if $V$ is endowed with an inner product and an orientation, then it turns out that every oriented orthonormal basis determines the same $n$-form, so in fact the $n$-form is completely determined by the inner product and the orientation.

For manifolds, this is fortunate, because on an oriented Riemannian manifold an inner product and an orientation are exactly the distinguished information we have for each tangent space. Thus every oriented Riemannian manifold has a uniquely determined volume form.

This is not the only way to determine a unique volume form. For example, a nondegenerate 2-form on a vector space determines a volume form, so every [symplectic manifold](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symplectic_manifold) has a uniquely determined volume form. Even more simply, if $M$ is [parallelizable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parallelizable_manifold) (e.g., any Lie group), then every choice of global frame determines a volume form (because it determines a choice of basis at each point).

Answer (score 3):

To make my comment better understandable: what is lurking in the background here is the Riesz representation theorem, which says that, after the choice of a scalar product on a vector space V,  there is a *unique* isomorphism between $V$ and $V^*$ given by $v\mapsto (w\mapsto \langle v, w\rangle)$.

While it is known that $V$ and $V^*$ are isomorphic, there is normally no natural choice for an isomorphism (you have to choose a basis, but this is arbitrary), but there is one once you have a scalar product.

So, while it is no surprise that the introduction of a scalar product allows you to define length (and, as a consequence, volume) and while it is also no surprise that $V$ and $V^*$ are isomorphic (in finite dimensions), it *should* come as a surprise to the naive observer that volume can be (naturally) calculated using elements from $V^*$ once you define length and angles for $V$.

Regarding your question to my comment: the calculation you cite from Spivak shows that with a scalar product the volume form does not depend on the basis, but remains invariant under transformations which preseve the scalar product. So the volume form depends *only* on the choice of scalar product (and orientation, of course), as mentioned before.

(Sorry, too long for a comment, not intended to answer all of your questions, only the first one).

Comment: Sorry, but what you mean by "[...] volume can be (naturally) calculated using elements from $V^{\ast}$"? In what sense arises the volume form uniquely if I have given an inner product? I cannot connect to your initial remarks about the identification between $V$ and its dual $V^{\ast}$? As I see it, Spivak shows that it is uniquely determined for all orthonormal bases in one orientation equivalence class.

Comment: @Stefan yes, correct. The point you seem to be missing is that this is exactly what you need. You choose a scalar product, you choose (any) oriented orthonormal base (ONB), and you get the volume form by the choice mentioned in your question. The particular choice of ONB is irrelevant, this is exactly  what results from the calculation you cite from Spivak. You may need a choice of basis to do actual calculations, but the result does not depend on this choice, as long as it is an ONB with respect to the scalar product.

Comment: @Stefan maybe you are not aware of the fact that there are exactly two equivalence classes of orthonormal bases which are distinguished by the orientation? I.e. if you have a scalar product and an orthonormal basis then every other orthonormal base wrt to that scalar product arises by a orthogonal transformation which is either orientation preserving or reversing.

Comment: Okay, think I got that. But what you wanna say then with your first three paragraphs, where you are talking about the identification of $V$ with $V^{\ast}$ by the scalar product?

Comment: @Stefan The Riesz representation theorem is the link from the geometry of a VS to its dual space. It's why you can calculate volumes using forms instead of caluting products of lengths. This is why i said it should come as a surprise that the volume  can be obtained by using forms. Once you have a scalar product you can transform geometric calculations (like calculation of volume) in $V$ into algebraic manipulations of elements from $V*$, which is not obvious in the first place (and this is what Spivak is trying to tell you, you can calculate volume using a uniquely determined $n$- form).

Comment: Okay, guess I see. But are you just trying to give intuitive arguments, or could you give a definite construction "scalar product $\rightarrow$ riesz rep thm $\rightarrow$ volume by algebraic combination of dual vectors"?

Comment: @Stefan the relation between vectors and forms is written in my answer explicitly. That this is an isomorphism is a fact which a detailed proof of which can be found in any LA textbook. The formal reasoning for the existence of the volume form is written down in the citation from Spivak's book in your question. While the existence proof may not be constructive enough for you, it is a valid proof (and not just an intuitive argument). I'm not really sure I understand what is missing from your point of view (apart from the intuitive understanding what this all means, where I tried to help out).

Comment: I do not see where Spivak in his arguments uses the isomorphisms of $V$ and $V^{\ast}$ as given by the scalar product?