# Orientation and volume form with certain property

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, tangent-spaces

I'm learning about differential forms and orientation. I encountered the following theorem:

> Let $M$ be an oriented Riemannian manifold. There exists a unique volume form $\omega$ such that for all $p\in M$ and every orthonormal, positively-oriented ordered basis $\{b_1,\dots, b_n\}$ of $T_pM$, $\omega_p(b_1,...,b_n)=1$.

I wasn't able to find any proof online or in Lee's book and I'm not sure how to approach this.
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Do you know how to do this for a single vector space equipped with a (pseudo) inner product and an orientation?

Comment: No, I'm not even sure what a pseudo inner product is

Comment: "pseudo" was just incase you wanted more generality. But ok if you're asking this question then surely you must know what a dot/inner product on a vector space is. Otherwise, I'd suggest you look that up before even attempting this.

Comment: I'm familiar with inner product, just don't know how to show this for a single vector space

Comment: See [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1709100/568204). The excerpt from Spivak's Calculus on manifolds contains a proof for the case of a single inner product space. Anyway, the volume form you seek is such that for a positively oriented coordinate chart $(U,x)$, we have $\omega|_U=\sqrt{|\det g_{ij}|}\,dx^1\wedge\cdots \wedge dx^n$. If you use this formula as the starting point, then you just have to show that in the overlap of two charts, the two definitions agree.

Comment: The statement doesn’t quite make sense. What does “with positive orientation” mean if you do not assume $M$ is an *oriented* smooth manifold.